# Decode methodID of a inputData Ethereum transaction without ABI

Tags: transactions

I know that the methodID is the first 4 bytes of the hash of the "methodName" and the "Parameters".

Every 2 characters are considered 1 byte, that's why it has 8 characters.

But what I want is to decode it, and get the "methodName" and the "Parameters" to decode the input data.

is it possible to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is publicly available you can use a database like [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory/).